# After Upgrading the Angular version from V9 to V17 i am getting errors in ng build command

Tags: angular, angular-material

Recently we upgraded  our angular from v9 to v16 after upgrading all packages I wanted to build the project but I am getting many errors. Below are the details of the versions which I am using
Node js - 18.18.0
Npm - 9.8.1
Angular - 17.1.1

here is my package.json -

```
{
    "name": "fuse",
    "version": "9.0.0",
    "license": "https://themeforest.net/licenses/terms/regular",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --open",
        "start-hmr": "ng serve --configuration hmr --source-map=false --hmr-warning=false",
        "start-hmr-sourcemaps": "ng serve --configuration hmr --source-map=true --hmr-warning=false",
        "build": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --dev",
        "build-stats": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --dev --stats-json",
        "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
        "build-prod-stats": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --stats-json",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/cdk": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/common": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/core": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/forms": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/localize": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/material": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/router": "17.1.1",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^16.0.0",
        "@ng-idle/core": "14.0.0",
        "@ng-idle/keepalive": "14.0.0",
        "@ngrx/effects": "17.0.1",
        "@ngrx/router-store": "17.0.1",
        "@ngrx/store": "17.0.1",
        "@ngrx/store-devtools": "17.0.1",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "12.0.0",
        "@swimlane/dragula": "3.8.0",
        "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "20.4.1",
        "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "20.1.0",
        "@types/crypto-js": "4.1.1",
        "@types/prismjs": "1.26.3",
        "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.17.0",
        "bootstrap": "5.3.0",
        "crypto-js": "4.1.1",
        "date-fns": "3.2.0",
        "guid-typescript": "1.0.9",
        "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
        "html2canvas": "1.4.1",
        "lodash": "4.17.15",
        "mat-select-filter": "^2.4.1",
        "mat-table-exporter": "^15.0.0",
        "moment": "2.30.0",
        "ngx-color-picker": "16.0.0",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "17.0.1",
        "ngx-device-detector": "7.0.0",
        "ngx-material-file-input": "^4.0.1",
        "ngx-quill": "24.0.4",
        "perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.5",
        "prismjs": "1.29.0",
        "quill": "^1.3.7",
        "rxjs": "7.8.1",
        "tslib": "2.6.2",
        "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
        "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
        "zone.js": "0.14.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "17.1.1",
        "@angular-eslint/builder": "17.2.1",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "17.2.1",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "17.2.1",
        "@angular-eslint/schematics": "17.2.1",
        "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "17.2.1",
        "@angular/cli": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "17.1.1",
        "@angular/language-service": "17.1.2",
        "@angularclass/hmr": "3.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "5.1.4",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
        "@types/lodash": "4.14.202",
        "@types/node": "20.10.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "6.20.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "6.20.0",
        "codelyzer": "6.0.2",
        "eslint": "8.56.0",
        "jasmine-core": "5.1.1",
        "karma": "6.4.2",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.2.0",
        "karma-coverage": "2.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "5.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "2.1.0",
        "ts-node": "10.9.2",
        "tslint": "5.18.0",
        "typescript": "5.2.2",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "4.10.1"
    }
}
```

I have tried the following things -
1. Imported the all packages into app.module.ts
2. Also updated the angular JSON

Here is the example app.module.ts code which we are using  -

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgIdleKeepaliveModule } from '@ng-idle/keepalive';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MatMomentDateModule, MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { FuseModule } from '@fuse/fuse.module';
import { FuseSharedModule } from '@fuse/shared.module';
import { FuseProgressBarModule, FuseSidebarModule, FuseThemeOptionsModule } from '@fuse/components';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { fuseConfig } from 'app/fuse-config';
import { DatePipe, PlatformLocation, APP_BASE_HREF, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import 'hammerjs';
import { QuillModule } from 'ngx-quill';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from 'app/app.component';
import { LayoutModule } from 'app/layout/layout.module';

import { MAT_DATE_FORMATS, DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';

import { LoaderComponent } from './common/loader/loader.component';
import { LoaderInterceptor } from './common/loader/loader.interceptor';
import { LoaderService } from './common/loader/loader.service';

import { BaseService } from './services/base.service';
import { ConfirmDialogComponent } from './common/confirm-dialog/confirm-dialog.component';
import { ShowDialogComponent } from './common/show-dialog/show-dialog.component';
import { DialogService } from './common/confirm-dialog/dialog.service';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ErrorInterceptor } from './helpers/error.interceptor';
import { BasicAuthInterceptor } from './helpers/basic-auth.interceptor';
import { LoginComponent } from './auth/login/login.component';
import { ProgressBarModelComponent } from './common/progress-bar-model/progress-bar-model.component';
import { HttpService } from './services/http.service';
import { IgmiteModule } from './main/igmite.module';
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { FakeDbService } from './fake-db/fake-db.service';
import { ProjectDashboardModule } from './dashboards/dashboard.module';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
// import { fuseperfectscrollbaroptions }
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
```

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoaderComponent,
        ConfirmDialogComponent,
        ShowDialogComponent,
        ProgressBarModelComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        QuillModule,
        // MatInputModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        // MatTableExporterModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        NgIdleKeepaliveModule.forRoot(),

        InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(FakeDbService, {
            delay: 0,
            passThruUnknownUrl: true
        }),

        // Material moment date module
        MatMomentDateModule,
        FormsModule,    //added here too
        ReactiveFormsModule, //added here too
        // Material
        MatButtonModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatDialogModule,

        // Fuse modules
        FuseModule.forRoot(fuseConfig),
        FuseProgressBarModule,
        FuseSharedModule,
        FuseSidebarModule,
        FuseThemeOptionsModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        // App modules
        LayoutModule,
        IgmiteModule,
        ProjectDashboardModule
    ],
    exports: [ 

        MatPaginatorModule ],
```

I am getting below errors I just wanted to run my applications-

```
Error: src/app/reports/vtp-monthly-report/vtp-monthly-report.component.html:45:20 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.

45                 <a [routerLink]="['./']" class="refresh-data mt-24 mt-md-0">
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/reports/vtp-monthly-report/vtp-monthly-report.component.ts:17:16
    17   templateUrl: './vtp-monthly-report.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component VTPMonthlyReportComponent.


Error: src/app/reports/vtp-monthly-report/vtp-monthly-report.component.html:46:21 - error NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.
2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

46                     <mat-icon [@animate]="{value:'*',params:{delay:'50ms',scale:'0.2'}}">refresh</mat-icon>
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/reports/vtp-monthly-report/vtp-monthly-report.component.ts:17:16
    17   templateUrl: './vtp-monthly-report.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component VTPMonthlyReportComponent.


Error: src/app/reports/vtp-monthly-report/vtp-monthly-report.component.html:180:59 - error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'matTableExporter'.

180                 [dataSource]="tableDataSource" #exporter="matTableExporter" [hiddenColumns]="[0]" matSort
                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/reports/vtp-monthly-report/vtp-monthly-report.component.ts:17:16
    17   templateUrl: './vtp-monthly-report.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component VTPMonthlyReportComponent.


Error: src/app/reports/vtp-monthly-report/vtp-monthly-report.component.html:180:77 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'hiddenColumns' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-table'.
1. If 'mat-table' is an Angular component and it has 'hiddenColumns' input, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.
2. If 'mat-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component.

180                 [dataSource]="tableDataSource" #exporter="matTableExporter" [hiddenColumns]="[0]" matSort
                                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/reports/vtp-monthly-report/vtp-monthly-report.component.ts:17:16
    17   templateUrl: './vtp-monthly-report.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component VTPMonthlyReportComponent.


Error: src/app/reports/vtp-monthly-report/vtp-monthly-report.component.html:181:38 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'fusePerfectScrollbarOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-table'.
1. If 'mat-table' is an Angular component and it has 'fusePerfectScrollbarOptions' input, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.
2. If 'mat-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component.

181                 fusePerfectScrollbar [fusePerfectScrollbarOptions]="{'suppressScrollX': false}">
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/reports/vtp-monthly-report/vtp-monthly-report.component.ts:17:16
    17   templateUrl: './vtp-monthly-report.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component VTPMonthlyReportComponent.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one imported Module breaks the whole module import process. I would focus on the first error, which is about Routing.

Since you use the latest version from Angular, you should see in the documentation that they changed a lot lately. https://angular.io/guide/router#defining-a-basic-route

Your application will not use a RoutingModule, but use the providers of your AppConfig and import the RouterOutlet and RouterLink directly into your AppComponent.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is any module which is breaking other one. I will suggest comment all and check one by one and see which module is breaking.